# google chart shows wrong data

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-visualization

I'm having some trouble creating a data chart with Google charts, I don't know why my chart is showing this way?

[image]

As you might see in the image the y value should be 2 but I'm getting a 3 or so. What can cause this problem?

This is my current code:

```
private DataTable GetData()
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    string cmd = "SELECT TotalShipped, TotalOnTime, TotalOnTime / TotalShipped * 100 AS LISC" +
" FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalShipped, SUM(CASE LISC WHEN 100 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS TotalOnTime" +
                   " FROM dbo.tbl_LISC) AS t";

    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, conn);

    adp.Fill(dt);

    return dt;

}
```

And:

```
private void BindChart()
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {

        dt = GetData();



        str.Append(@"<script type=*text/javascript*> google.load( *visualization*, *1*, {packages:[*corechart*]});

                   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                   function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('number', 'TotalOnTime');     

    data.addColumn('number', 'LISC');


    data.addRows(1);");


        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {

            str.Append("data.setValue( " + i + "," + 1 + "," + "'" + dt.Rows[i]["LISC"].ToString() + "');");

            str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 0 + "," + dt.Rows[i]["TotalOnTime"].ToString() + ") ;");

        }

        str.Append(" var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));");

        str.Append(" chart.draw(data, {width: 1850, height: 500,bars: 'horizontal', title: 'Materiales',");

        str.Append("hAxis: {title: 'LISC', titleTextStyle: {color: 'green'},viewWindow:{max:100,min:0}}");


        str.Append("}); }");

        str.Append("</script>");

        lt.Text = str.ToString().Replace('*', '"');

    }
    catch
    {

    }

}
```

This is the query result:

[image]

Any help or comments on this is helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The y value is correct. Check your values on your Y-axis, they are divided in values of 3/4's. 
Your graph is somewhere between 2.5 and 3.25, and a bit closer to 3.25 than 2.5, so a good guess is that it's around 2.

This is caused by googles function to automatically decide how many and to what values to attach your gridlines.

Check out the configuarion methods [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Configuration_Options), and jump down to vAxis.gridlines to see what you can vary to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: the only additional format that kinda helped was "vAxis.gridlines.count", I'm not totally satisfied with the result but I guess it works, might try another alternative instead of using Google chart.

Comment: I see you've entered `hAxis.viewWindow.min` and max. Try doing the same with `vAxis.viewWindow.min = 0`, and work from there. This might help you control the generation "prettier".